# Add carrier column to orders table in Prestashop back-office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying add "carrier" column to orders table. I know I need to add that field in fields_list array in AdminOrdersController.php, but when I expanding array on field `carrier` I got `unknown column 'carrier'` error in BO. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: To whoever came from search like I just did: see https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/templating/admin-views/ and https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/override-decorate-controller/, "*Since PrestaShop 1.7, the back office is being progressively migrated to the Symfony framework. Even though modules are no longer allowed to override a complete controller like before (it was highly discouraged anyway), we have introduced new powerful and more efficient ways to customize the Back Office.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit late as Markus give you guide how to do it. I have tested this override.

In `override/controllers/admin` create new file `AdminOrdersController.php` with following code:

```
<?php

class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->table = 'order';
        $this->className = 'Order';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->addRowAction('view');
        $this->explicitSelect = true;
        $this->allow_export = true;
        $this->deleted = false;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();

        $this->_select = '
        a.id_currency,
        a.id_order AS id_pdf,
        CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), \'. \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
        osl.`name` AS `osname`,
        IF(carrier.`name` = "0", "-", carrier.`name`) AS `carriername`,
        os.`color`,
        IF((SELECT so.id_order FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` so WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer AND so.id_order < a.id_order LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1) as new,
        country_lang.name as cname,
        IF(a.valid, 1, 0) badge_success';

        $this->_join = '
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country` country ON address.id_country = country.id_country
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang` country_lang ON (country.`id_country` = country_lang.`id_country` AND country_lang.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'carrier` carrier ON a.id_carrier = carrier.id_carrier
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')';
        $this->_orderBy = 'id_order';
        $this->_orderWay = 'DESC';
        $this->_use_found_rows = true;

        $statuses = OrderState::getOrderStates((int)$this->context->language->id);
        foreach ($statuses as $status) {
            $this->statuses_array[$status['id_order_state']] = $status['name'];
        }

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_order' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('ID'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
            ),
            'reference' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Reference')
            ),
            'new' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('New client'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'type' => 'bool',
                'tmpTableFilter' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
                'callback' => 'printNewCustomer'
            ),
            'customer' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Customer'),
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
        );

        if (Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE')) {
            $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
                'company' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Company'),
                    'filter_key' => 'c!company'
                ),
            ));
        }

        $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
            'total_paid_tax_incl' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Total'),
                'align' => 'text-right',
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency' => true,
                'callback' => 'setOrderCurrency',
                'badge_success' => true
            ),
            'payment' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Payment')
            ),
            'carriername' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Carrier'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xl',
                'filter_key' => 'carrier!name',
                'filter_type' => 'text',
                'order_key' => 'carrier!name'
            ),
            'osname' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Status'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'color' => 'color',
                'list' => $this->statuses_array,
                'filter_key' => 'os!id_order_state',
                'filter_type' => 'int',
                'order_key' => 'osname'
            ),
            'date_add' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Date'),
                'align' => 'text-right',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'filter_key' => 'a!date_add'
            ),
            'id_pdf' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('PDF'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'callback' => 'printPDFIcons',
                'orderby' => false,
                'search' => false,
                'remove_onclick' => true
            )
        ));

        if (Country::isCurrentlyUsed('country', true)) {
            $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('
            SELECT DISTINCT c.id_country, cl.`name`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` o
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('orders', 'o').'
            INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` a ON a.id_address = o.id_address_delivery
            INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country` c ON a.id_country = c.id_country
            INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang` cl ON (c.`id_country` = cl.`id_country` AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
            ORDER BY cl.name ASC');

            $country_array = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $country_array[$row['id_country']] = $row['name'];
            }

            $part1 = array_slice($this->fields_list, 0, 3);
            $part2 = array_slice($this->fields_list, 3);
            $part1['cname'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Delivery'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'list' => $country_array,
                'filter_key' => 'country!id_country',
                'filter_type' => 'int',
                'order_key' => 'cname'
            );
            $this->fields_list = array_merge($part1, $part2);
        }

        $this->shopLinkType = 'shop';
        $this->shopShareDatas = Shop::SHARE_ORDER;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('id_order')) {
            // Save context (in order to apply cart rule)
            $order = new Order((int)Tools::getValue('id_order'));
            $this->context->cart = new Cart($order->id_cart);
            $this->context->customer = new Customer($order->id_customer);
        }

        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'updateOrderStatus' => array('text' => $this->l('Change Order Status'), 'icon' => 'icon-refresh')
        );

        AdminController::__construct();
    }

}
```

So same as Markus explanantion, I have joinned `carrier` table then in query select added name (have set to display - if no carriers) and displayed it in `field_list` with working filter and order.
Notice that in this override you do not need to call `parent::__construct();` but  `AdminController::__construct();`.
Also do clear PrestaShop cache if needed.

Answer (score 5):

You should edit the $this->_select, $this->_join and $this->field_list variables in order to show the carrier.

The $this->_join should contain the following

```
LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_carrier` oc ON (a.`id_order` = oc.`id_order`)
LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'carrier` carr ON (oc.`id_carrier` = carr.`id_carrier`)
```

Then, in the select you have the carr table, so you can use

```
carr.name as `carriername`
```

To retrieve the carrier. Then, in the fields list you should use something like

```
'carriername' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Carrier')
),
```

Do mind that the first 2 items should be valid SQL, so use spaces and commas on the right places (depending on where you added the code). Also, you should use an override for this functionality, so you can still get Prestashop updates (see http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingacontroller).