# Add Carrier column in admin order list prestashop 1.7.7.5

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I'm under prestashop 1.7.7.5, I want add in BO order list a column to display carrier name, I have succeed to add the column with the hookActionOrderGridDefinitionModifier, but I have a problem to add carriername field in ArdminOrdersController.

I test to make an override, but without success nothing doesn't change, neither if I modify directly the AdminOrdersController.php in /controllers/admin, I also try with hookActionAdminOrdersListingFieldsModifier without success.

The override is the file in this ask : [Add carrier column to orders table in Prestashop back-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785470/add-carrier-column-to-orders-table-in-prestashop-back-office)

I have already try to clear cache in performances tab and clear the dev and prod folder in var/cache

My hook for fields modifier :

```
public function hookActionAdminOrdersListingFieldsModifier($params)
{
    if (isset($params['select'])) {
        $params['select'] .= 'carr.name as `carriername`';
    }

    if (isset($params['join'])) {
        $params['join'] .= 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_carrier` oc ON (a.`id_order` = oc.`id_order`)
                            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'carrier` carr ON (oc.`id_carrier` = carr.`id_carrier`)';
    }

    $params['fields']['carriername'] = [
        'title' => $this->trans('Carrier', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'align' => 'text-center',
        'class' => 'fixed-width-xl',
        'filter_key' => 'carrier!name',
        'filter_type' => 'text',
        'order_key' => 'carrier!name',
    ];
}
```

My hook for adding carrier column:

```
public function hookActionOrderGridDefinitionModifier(array $params)
{

    /** @var GridDefinitionInterface $definition */
    $definition = $params['definition'];

    /** @var FilterCollection $filters */
    $filters = $definition->getFilters();

    /** @var ColumnCollection */
    $columns = $definition->getColumns();

    $columns
        ->addAfter('country_name',
            (new DataColumn('carrier'))
                ->setName($this->trans('Carrier', array(), 'Admin.Global'))
                ->setOptions([
                    'field' => 'carriername',
                ])
        );


}
```

Comment: I noticed you implemented a mixed solution between pre 1.7.7.x and post 1.7.7 Prestashop versions. As mentioned here https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/24082 Prestashop uses Grid component from Symfony since 1.7.7 and you have correctly implemented the ActionOrderGridDefinitionModifier but not the actionOrderGridQueryBuilderModifier. You need to implement it using Symfony's QueryBuilder, look at this official doc https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/grid/tutorials/modify-grid-in-module/ for a starting point.
Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Prestashop 1.7.8.1 source code directly, because the hook is not working, so this is a workaround.

src/Core/Grid/Definition/Factory/OrderGridDefinitionFactory.php

```
protected function getColumns()
{
     $columns = (new ColumnCollection())
        .....
        ->add((new DataColumn('carrier'))
        ->setName($this->trans('Carrier', [], 'Admin.Global'))
        ->setOptions([
            'field' => 'carrier_name',
        ])
```

src/Core/Grid/Query/OrderQueryBuilder.php

```
private function getBaseQueryBuilder(array $filters)
{
    $qb = $this->connection
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from($this->dbPrefix . 'orders', 'o')
        ->leftJoin('o', $this->dbPrefix . 'customer', 'cu', 'o.id_customer = cu.id_customer')
        ->leftJoin('o', $this->dbPrefix . 'carrier', 'ca', 'o.id_carrier = ca.id_carrier')


public function getSearchQueryBuilder(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    $qb = $this
        ->getBaseQueryBuilder($searchCriteria->getFilters())
        ->addSelect($this->getCustomerField() . ' AS `customer`')
        ->addSelect('o.id_order, o.id_carrier, o.reference, o.total_paid_tax_incl, os.paid, osl.name AS osname')
        ->addSelect('o.id_currency, cur.iso_code')
        ->addSelect('o.current_state, o.id_customer')
        ->addSelect('cu.`id_customer` IS NULL as `deleted_customer`')
        ->addSelect('os.color, o.payment, s.name AS shop_name')
        ->addSelect('o.date_add, cu.company, cl.name AS country_name, o.invoice_number, o.delivery_number')
        ->addSelect('o.id_carrier, ca.name as carrier_name')
```

Then, go to your admin order page,[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAn2c.png)

## seems, need to add filter function for carrier later.

well, hope the above could bring ideas for you, happy Chrismas.

Answer (score 0):

Almost works.... - probably you should change this part:

```
...
'filter_key' => 'carrier!name',
'filter_type' => 'text',
'order_key' => 'carrier!name',
...
```

by this:

```
'filter_key' => 'carr!name',
'filter_type' => 'text',
'order_key' => 'carr!name',
```

In my case (PrestaShop v. 1.7.6.9) I applied additional code directly / dirty in `/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php`
starting from line number 102 as follows:

```
$this->_select .= '
   ,
   carr.name as `carriername`
';

$this->_join .= '
   LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_carrier` oc ON (a.`id_order` = oc.`id_order`)
   LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'carrier` carr ON (oc.`id_carrier` = carr.`id_carrier`)
';

$this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
    'carriername' => array(
        'title' => $this->trans('Carrier', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
        'filter_key' => 'carr!name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'align' => 'text-center',
        'class' => 'fixed-width-xl',
        'filter_key' => 'carr!name',
        'filter_type' => 'text',
        'order_key' => 'carr!name',
    ),
));
```

as a result we have Carrier column in orders list / Presta admin orders list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Prestashop 1.7.8.7
`src/Core/Grid/Query/OrderQueryBuilder.php` just change

```
 $likeComparisonFilters = [
            'reference' => 'o.`reference`',
            'company' => 'cu.`company`',
            'payment' => 'o.`payment`',
            'customer' => $this->getCustomerField(),
        ];
```

to:

```
$likeComparisonFilters = [
            'reference' => 'o.`reference`',
            'company' => 'cu.`company`',
            'payment' => 'o.`payment`',
            'carrier' => 'ca.name',
            'customer' => $this->getCustomerField(),
        ];
```